# Monkey patching env variables for pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have an app.py file with variables being loaded from my template.yaml file.

```
KINESIS_VALID = os.environ['KINESIS_VALID']
KINESIS_INVALID = os.environ['KINESIS_INVALID']
```

I've created a conftest.py file in my tests directory and set a function to monkeypatch test variables:

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def env_setup(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv('KINESIS_VALID', 'kinesis-valid-test')
    monkeypatch.setenv('KINESIS_INVALID', 'kinesis-invalid-test)
```

My test file is in tests/unit/test_handler.py and the conftest.py is in the same directory as test_handler.py.

When I run the test, I'm getting KeyyError on KINESIS_VALID from where it's being defined in app.py (KINESIS_VALID = os.environ['KINESIS_VALID'])

The variables are being defined in app.py and I added a conftest.py to the directory app.py is in but the same error occurs. Not sure if I'm missing something in configuration or I'm not defining either the test variables or app.py variables correctly.

Comment: Maybe the code is called before the patching occurs, e.g. on module level? If it were called in a function or method, it should actually work as is.